# How do I get to the Catacomb in Chapter 2?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I am trying to complete the quest "Of Flickering Hearts" and the "Symbol of Death". However, the map marks the location north of the Vergen, and the only route I have found there takes me through the battle-field, and I get killed easily there.

Is there another route which I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complete of **Flickering Hearts**/Succubus you need the surgical instruments (you can buy them from a woman merchant) and you need to get to the catacombs and inspect a freshly dead body, there is a way to get there without crossing the battlefield (hint: look for a way of crossing the river, take the exit from Vergen past Iorveth's base). Once you have found and inspected the dead body talk to Dandelion.

You can do the **Symbol of Death** in the Catacombs at the same time (hint: go to the lower level and find the ghost of Ekhart Henessa).